# Measure for classification where model predicts a class with a given confidence

Tags: classification

I currently have a model which predicts one of four classes and gives a confidence with its output. How can I score my model taking into account the confidence the model should be penalized if a confident answer is incorrect and penalized less when a low confidence answer is incorrect?

Comment: Assuming the 'confidence' can be expressed as a probability, you can use [tag:scoring-rules]

Comment: @Rickyfox If I understand the question correctly, there is no probability assigned to each class, but there is a decision for one class and this decision has a confidence. It is not clear whether this can be reformulated as a probability, and there appear to be no probabilities for the other classes. Scoring rules like the Bier score are thus not applicable, I think, because they require a probability estimate for the actually occured class.